# Comparing Two Iterable Strings in Spark scala Over Compact Buffer from common Key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, rdd

I have cogrouped two RDDs' and I have to compare Iterable strings in the compact Buffer of the result RDD, Comparison is in this way

1 ) If right compactbuffer value is empty , keep the left compactbuffer value.

2) If the left compactbuffer value buffer is empty, keep the right buffer only when there is 'I' in it.

3) If the left compactbuffer value is not empty and the  right compactbuffer value is also not empty with "I" in it in that case take the right buffer.

4) If the left compactbuffer value is not empty and the  right compactbuffer value is also not empty keep and the right buffer has no "I" in it,then discard both the values and entire entry should be gone from the rdd.

Input:

```
res4: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Iterable[String], Iterable[String]))] = MapPartitionsRDD[25] at cogroup at <console>:57

Array[(String, (Iterable[String], Iterable[String]))] = 
Array((6,(CompactBuffer(6,surya,1003,null),CompactBuffer(6,surya,1030,D))), 

(5,(CompactBuffer(5,karun,1007,null),CompactBuffer(5,nirav,1023,I))), 

(9,(CompactBuffer(9,pranav,1010,null),CompactBuffer())), 

(3,(CompactBuffer(3,riahana,1006,null),CompactBuffer(3,rohit,1020,I))),

(1,(CompactBuffer(1,shubham,1001,null),CompactBuffer(1,yuvraj,1070,I))))
```

I need this output please help:

Output :

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

5,nirav,1023,I

9,pranav,1010,null

3,rohit,1020,I

1,yuvraj,1070,I
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes @AlbertoBonsanto I tried but I was not able pull out the correct output.I am new to spark :(

Comment: And what happens if both aren't empty and the right and left don't have the letter `l`?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Leave that case

Comment: What do you mean with leave?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto If both aren't empty and the right buffer don't have " I " in it , I don't need both of them in final output.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto can you help me please :)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto are you trying ? I am thinking about filtering and mapping it based on second Iterable string values ...

Comment: You should improve the list of requirements, it's a bit messy

Comment: Wait a minute I'll update it  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow, but this will hopefully give you an idea:

```
val result: RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] = data
        .filter(_._2._2.exists(_.endsWith("I")))
        .mapValues {
          case (left, right) => (left, right.filter(_.endsWith("I")))
        }.mapValues {
          case (left, right) => right.headOption.map(_ => right).getOrElse(left)
        }
```

Or you could do a simple `right.isEmpty` check with an `if`/`else` if you prefer.

Comment: Your solution gives me left buffer value also when right buffer does not have " I " in it . How to discard that value ? 
Its giving me  this value too    6,surya,1003,null

Array((6,CompactBuffer(6,surya,1003,null)), (5,List(5,nirav,1023,I)), (9,CompactBuffer(9,pranav,1010,null)), (3,List(3,rohit,1020,I)), (1,List(1,yuvraj,1070,I)))

Comment: As @AlbertoBonsanto told you several times, your requirement remains unclear--in this case in terms of what happens when both `Iterable`s are nonempty and the right has no I's. Regardless, the goal is to give you the information you need to solve the problem yourself--not to do all your work for you.

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear in my requirements , it was my first question on stackoverflow , basically when both Iterables are non empty and the right has no I's , in that case we will not take any values from both sides. Thanks @Vidya for pointing out my mistake , I'll take care in future and Thank you so much for the solution , you are best  :)

Comment: So when you say "take nothing," do you mean an empty `Iterable`? Do you mean the entire entry in the `RDD` is gone? Define that precisely.

Comment: Yeah the entire entry in the resultant RDD should go .

Comment: I added an update that might work. Even if it doesn't, hopefully it will give you the ideas you need.

Comment: Thanx a lot @Vidya you are the real MVP :)

Comment: Since you found the answer helpful, an upvote would be appreciated.